# How to use Task.WhenAll to wait for third party Async method call

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, task-parallel-library

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours and haven't been able to understand why this isn't working.  I have a TPL Dataflow batch block that accepts a batch of files that I want to upload.  I need to be able to use a cancellation token so I am using the UploadAsync method.  I want to process each job in the batch in parallel with one another but I only want to process one batch at a time.

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<TInput>(input =>
{
    DoWork(input);
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
   TaskScheduler = new CustomScheduler(1, ApartmentState.MTA, ThreadPriority.Normal) 
});

void DoWork(TInput input)
{
    var castedMessage = input as Tuple<string, >[];
    if (castedMessage == null) return;
        ProcessBatch(castedMessage);
}

public void ProcessBatch(Tuple<string, string>[] batch)
{
    if (batch == null) return;


    Task<Tuple<bool, long>>[] batchUploadTaskArray = new Task<Tuple<bool, long>>[batch.Length * 2];

    int taskArrayIndex = 0;

    foreach(var job in batch)
    {
        if (job == null) return;

        var chunkSegment = job.Item1;
        var indexSegment = job.Item2;

        var uploadTask1 = uploader.putFileAsync(job.Item1.LocalFilePath, job.Item1.RemoteChunkFilePath);
        uploadTask1.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if(task.Result.Item1)
                    UploaderStatsManager.Instance.UpdateUploadDuration(task.Result.Item2);
            }, TaskScheduler.Default
        );

        batchUploadTaskArray[taskArrayIndex++] = uploadTask1;
        batchUploadTaskArray[taskArrayIndex++] = uploader.putFileAsync(idxLocalFilepath, indexSegment.RemoteIndexFilePath);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(batchUploadTaskArray);             
    Console.WriteLine("Done uploading");
}


//Method A - AWS uploader class
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
public async override Task<Tuple<bool, long>> putFileAsync(string filePath, string destPath)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(mAccessKeyId, mSecretAccessKeyId, new AmazonS3Config
    {
        RegionEndpoint = !String.Equals(mRegion.DisplayName, "Unknown") ? mRegion : RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
    }))
    {
        using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client))
        {
            using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                var transferRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    Key = destPath.TrimStart('/'),
                    InputStream = file,
                    BucketName = mBucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                };

                transferRequest.UploadProgressEvent += DisplayFileProgress;

                var fInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                sw.Start();
                await transferUtility.UploadAsync(transferRequest, cts.Token).ContinueWith((task) => sw.Stop());
            }
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<bool, long>(true, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}


//Method B - Alternate FTP class
public Task<Tuple<bool, long>> putFileAsync(string filePath, string destPath)
{
    return Task<Tuple<bool, long>>.Run(() =>
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var putRC = ftp.putFile(filePath, destPath);
        sw.Stop();
        return new Tuple<bool, long>(putRC, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    });
}


//uploader stats class
public class UploaderStatsManager
{
    public ConcurrentQueue<double> uploadDurationQueue;
    private static UploaderStatsManager instance;

    private UploaderStatsManager()
    {
        uploadDurationQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<double>();
    }

    public static UploaderStatsManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (statsLock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new UploaderStatsManager();
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    internal void UpdateUploadDuration(double uploadDuration)
    {
        double durationOut = 0.0;
        bool rc = true;

        if(uploadDurationQueue.Count >= 12)
            rc = uploadDurationQueue.TryDequeue(out durationOut);

        if(rc)
            uploadDurationQueue.Enqueue(uploadDuration);
    }
}
```

I am also using another framework for the FTP file put that does not provide an async file put.  If I use Method A, the first batch process hangs at the Task.WaitAll.  If I use Method B, only one batch is processed at a time and the batches don't hang at the Task.WaitAll.  I have tried to change the ProcessBatch method to an async method and use "await Task.WhenAll" instead of Task.WaitAll and this works for MethodA and MethodB but it does not prevent batches from processing in parallel.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are throwing away the result of `uploadTask1.ContinueWith`. Probably, you should wait for that as well. Fix this issue and I'll take another look. In general, I recommend to not use ContinueWith and rather use `await`. Sometimes this means that you must extract some code into another method or async delegate.

Comment: It's not being thrown away.  I omitted the code for brevity.

Comment: Then please add that code because as it stands there is clearly a bug which I cannot ignore.

Comment: @usr I updated the code per your recommendation.

Comment: I see. This is a misunderstanding. I wasn't concerned with the body of the lambda you pass to ContinueWith. I was concerned that you ignore the Task returned by ContinueWith. This task runs concurrently with other code because you never wait for it. This can cause races.

Comment: Is this being called in a UI thread or ASP.NET request thread?

Comment: I have a TPL Dataflow pipeline used for video encoding in multiple bitrates and muxing files in multiple formats.  The pipeline consists of the following: UI thread posting AV frames to BufferBlock -> BroadcastBlock -> TransformBlock -> ActionBlock_1 -> BufferBlock -> BatchBlock -> ActionBlock_2. The Transform block and the ActionBlocks use the LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler since our pipeline needs to operate serially.

ActionBlock_2 (what I posted above) is responsible for uploading the resulting video files.  Is it helpful to see code for the remaining TPL blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  Within the putFileAsync method, the uploadAsync returns a Task.  I just call Task.WaitAll on that task and remove the async keyword from the method header.

```
public override Task<Tuple<bool, long>> putFileAsync(string filePath, string destPath)
{
    return Task<Tuple<bool, long>>.Run(() =>
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(mAccessKeyId, mSecretAccessKeyId, new AmazonS3Config
        {
            RegionEndpoint = !String.Equals(mRegion.DisplayName, "Unknown") ? mRegion : RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
        }))
        {
            using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client))
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    var transferRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                    {
                        Key = destPath.TrimStart('/'),
                        InputStream = file,
                        BucketName = mBucketName,
                        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                    };

                    transferRequest.UploadProgressEvent += DisplayFileProgress;

                    var fInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                    sw.Start();
                    Task uploadTask = transferUtility.UploadAsync(transferRequest, cts.Token).ContinueWith((task)=>sw.Stop());
                    Task.WaitAll(uploadTask);
                }
            }
        }

        return new Tuple<bool, long>(true, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    });
}
```